# Renormalization Group Invariance of Scattering Amplitude

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

How can one show that the scattering amplitude is renormalization group invariant using the fact that the bare Green's function $G_0^{(n)}$ is renormalization group invariant?

We have:

$(1) \quad G_0^{(n)}=Z^{n/2}G^{(n)}_R$

so that the amputated Green's functions are related by:

$(2) \quad \Gamma_0^{(n)}=Z^{-n/2}\Gamma^{(n)}_R$

But don't the Feynman rules say that the scattering amplitude is $\Gamma^{(n)}_R$ multiplied by $Z^{1/2}$ for each external leg? Then

$(3) \quad M=Z^{n/2}\Gamma^{(n)}_R=Z^n \Gamma_0^{(n)}$

which is not RG invariant since $Z$ is not RG-invariant, but $\Gamma_0^{(n)}$ is, so that the product $Z^n \Gamma_0^{(n)}$ can't be RG invariant.